# compilation of modulemap in clang

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang

I've read specification of modulemap metalanguage from http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html I added file to my project and updated podspec. But when I'm trying to lib lint I got errors in mentioned file (compilation fails). I'm searching for command line tool which process me my modeluemap. I believe I should execute clang in some way, but have no idea how to do this :/ I couldn't find answer on google for this.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I did it in different way, not using frameworks.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile it for clang ? What is the big picture ?